# Consolidating multiple if statements

Tags: java, android, if-statement, switch-statement, logic

I have the following code which relies on multiple different if-statements. I am making a Cribbage score counting app for android. The code shown is just for team Blue but whatever I end up with for team Blue will be used for teams red and green as well. What I have right now works, but it's bulky. I'm new to java and was hoping for some pointers on best practices about consolidating the code to it is easier to read and maintain.

```
    if(blueTeamScore >= ENDGAMESCORE) {
        String baseVictoryText = "Blue Team has won!";
        TextView winningTeamTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winningTeam);

        if(hasThreePlayer == false) {
            winningTeamTextView.setText(baseVictoryText);
            if (hasSkunk == true) {
                if (redTeamScore <= 90) {
                    winningTeamTextView.setText(baseVictoryText + "\nAnd Red Team got Skunked");
                }
            }
        }
        if(hasThreePlayer == true) {
            winningTeamTextView.setText(baseVictoryText);
            if (hasSkunk == true) {
                if ((redTeamScore <= 90) && (greenTeamScore <= 90)) {
                    winningTeamTextView.setText(baseVictoryText + "\nAnd Red and Green Teams got Skunked");
                }
                if ((redTeamScore <= 90) && (greenTeamScore >= 90)) {
                    winningTeamTextView.setText(baseVictoryText + "\nAnd Red Team got Skunked");
                }
                if ((redTeamScore >= 90) && (greenTeamScore <= 90)) {
                    winningTeamTextView.setText(baseVictoryText + "\nAnd Green Team got Skunked");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I know Boolean variables can't be used in switch statements (too bad) but is there something else similar that would help concentrate my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still count myself as fairly new but here's what I would have written.  I edited this a few times.

```
if (hasSkunk) {
    if (!hasThreePlayer) {
        if (redTeamScore<=90) {
            baseVictoryText += "\nAnd Red Team got Skunked";
        }
    } else {
        if ((redTeamScore <= 90) && (greenTeamScore <= 90)) {
            baseVictoryText += "\nAnd Red and Green Teams got Skunked";
        } else if (redTeamScore <= 90) {
            baseVictoryText += "\nAnd Red Team got Skunked";
        } else if (greenTeamScore <= 90) {
            baseVictoryText += "\nAnd Green Team got Skunked";
        }
    }
}
winningTeamTextView.setText(baseVictoryText);
```

Assuming that you don't mind changing baseVictoryText (not a constant).  Otherwise assign it to something else and use that

Not assuming the 'hasSkunk' means that at least one of the teams has <90, otherwise the last else if becomes else ...

'Else if' is better in theory here because of performance - the ifs are only evaluated until one is true.  That's not a problem here but if one of the conditions is the result of a hefty method ...

A bunch of Else Ifs like this works very much like switch with break.

Answer (score 1):

You can try ternary operators ?: . Example in above code i have just simplified some part . You can try something similar in else

```
        if(!hasThreePlayer) {
            winningTeamTextView.setText(hasSkunk&&redTeamScore<=90 ? baseVictoryText + "\nAnd Red Team got Skunked" : baseVictoryText);
        }
        else {
            winningTeamTextView.setText(baseVictoryText);
            if (hasSkunk) {
                if ((redTeamScore <= 90) && (greenTeamScore <= 90)) {
                    winningTeamTextView.setText(baseVictoryText + "\nAnd Red and Green Teams got Skunked");
                }
                if ((redTeamScore <= 90) && (greenTeamScore >= 90)) {
                    winningTeamTextView.setText(baseVictoryText + "\nAnd Red Team got Skunked");
                }
                if ((redTeamScore >= 90) && (greenTeamScore <= 90)) {
                    winningTeamTextView.setText(baseVictoryText + "\nAnd Green Team got Skunked");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on ternary operators, good thing for me to go and look up.

Answer (score 0):

A bit cleaner as only set the textField in one place, no need to == a boolean, if should be branched because if one succeed the other will fail. a slight variation on the initial response.

```
if(blueTeamScore >= ENDGAMESCORE) {
    String victoryText = "Blue Team has won!";

    if(!hasThreePlayer && hasSkunk && redTeamScore <= 90) {
        victoryText += "\nAnd Red Team got Skunked");

    }else if(hasThreePlayer && hasSkunk) {
       if (redTeamScore <= 90 && greenTeamScore <= 90) {
          victoryText +=  "\nAnd Red and Green Teams got Skunked";
       }else if (redTeamScore <= 90) {
          victoryText +=  "\nAnd Red Team got Skunked";
       }else if (greenTeamScore <= 90) {
          victoryText += "\nAnd Green Team got Skunked";
       }
    }

    TextView winningTeamTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winningTeam);
    //maybe check for null textfield here?
    winningTeamTextView.setText(victoryText);
}
```

but i would break out into a function

```
 if(blueTeamScore >= ENDGAMESCORE) {
    String victoryText = "Blue Team has won!";
    if(hasSkunk){
        victoryText += getSkunkText(hasThreePlayer, redTeamScore, greenTeamScore)
    }

    TextView winningTeamTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winningTeam);
    //maybe check for null textfield here?
    winningTeamTextView.setText(victoryText);
}
```

Function:

```
private String getSkunkText(boolean hasThreePlayer, int redTeamScore, int greenTeamScore){
    String skunkText  = ""
    if(!hasThreePlayer) {
        skunkText = redTeamScore <= 90 ? "\nAnd Red Team got Skunked") : skunkText;
    }else if (redTeamScore <= 90 && greenTeamScore <= 90) {
        skunkText =  "\nAnd Red and Green Teams got Skunked";
    }else if ( redTeamScore <= 90) {
        skunkText =  "\nAnd Red Team got Skunked";
    }else if (greenTeamScore <= 90) {
        skunkText = "\nAnd Green Team got Skunked";
    }
    return skunkText; 
}
```